# Jquery css color is changing for every selector, but font-size is not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am working with google maps and I have an array of markers which looks like this:

```
var locations = [
        [{
            id: 1,
            lat: 51.5239935252832,
            lng: 5.137663903579778,
            content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
        }],
        [{
            id: 2,
            lat: 51.523853342911906,
            lng: 5.1377765563584035,
            content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
        }],
        [{
            id: 3,
            lat: 51.5237298485607,
            lng: 5.137969675407476,
            content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
        }],
        [{
            id: 4,
            lat: 51.52355628836575,
            lng: 5.138066234932012,
            content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
        }],
        [{
            id: 5,
            lat: 51.52340275379578,
            lng: 5.138211074218816,
            content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
        }],
        [{
            id: 6,
            lat: 51.523199152806626,
            lng: 5.138382735595769,
            content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
        }],
        [{
            id: 7,
            lat: 51.5229955509073,
            lng: 5.138511481628484,
            content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
        }],
        [{
            id: 8,
            lat: 51.52280529912936,
            lng: 5.138543668136663,
            content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
        }],
        [{
            id: 9,
            lat: 51.523596340777075,
            lng: 5.138463201866216,
            content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
        }],
        [{
            id: 700,
            lat: 51.523372714362736,
            lng: 5.1386992362595265,
            content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
        }],
        [{
            id: 101,
            lat: 51.52329594683302,
            lng: 5.138838711128301,
            content: 'Kids Jungalow Giraffe'
        }]
```

Than I loop trough the array of markers and set an html marker to every position like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng({
        lat: locations[i][0].lat,
        lng: locations[i][0].lng
    });
    var number = locations[i][0].id;
    var marker_html = '<div id="' + number + '"><div class="rich-marker"><span class="number-id">' + number + '</span></div></div>';

    var marker = new RichMarker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        flat: true,
        anchor: RichMarkerPosition.MIDDLE,
        content: marker_html
    });
}
```

Than I want to change the css styling of the class `number-id` on zoom level 18 like this:

```
map.addListener('zoom_changed', function () {
        // Limit the zoom level
        if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);

        // for loop door locaties
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            setMarkerSize(i);
        }
    });

    function setMarkerSize(i) {
        var infobox = locations[i][0].infobox;
        var id = locations[i][0].id;

      if (map.getZoom() === 18) {
            $('.rich-marker').css({ 'display' : 'block', 'width' : '20px', 'height' : '20px' });
            $('.number-id').css({ 'display' : 'block', 'font-size' : '12px'});

            if (id >= 100) {
                console.log(id);
                console.log($('[data-id="' + id + '"]'));

                $('#' + id).find('.number-id').css('font-size', '10px');
                $('#' + id).find('.number-id').css('color', 'red');
            }

            infobox.setOptions({ pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-93, -22) });
        }

    }
```

The color is changing all above 100, but the font-size is only changing for the last object in the array why is that??

Comment: `if( id >= 100 ){` here where is value of `id` coming from ?

Comment: @dreamweiver sorry forget to mention that one

Comment: since id is not constructed in a loop, its value is constant inside the if , so selector `$('#' + id).find('.number-id')` will only only single value, because of the id selector used .which means there is no way the css will be applied to all elements with `id>=100`.

Comment: @dreamweiver but why the color is changing for all above 100?

Comment: I don't think so that is happening because of that piece of code. Could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net. so that it will be easy to debug

Comment: @RachelGallen it is a typo because that is last resort solution to set them all to 10px.

Comment: @dreamweiver as you can see it is in a for loop

Comment: @Beginnerprogrammer like dreamweiver said, create a jsfiddle

Comment: Hmmm that makes sense,anyway can you create a jsfiddle

Comment: What is `infobox`?

Comment: @geocodezip it is a library for custom infowindows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you process a marker in your loop you are setting **all** `font-size` properties to 12px:

```
$('.number-id').css({
    'display': 'block',
    'font-size': '12px'
  });
```

Then you set the `font-size` of the *current* marker to "10px".  That leaves only that last one you set at "10px".

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/369tuhLL/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng({
      lat: locations[i][0].lat,
      lng: locations[i][0].lng
    });
    bounds.extend(myLatLng);
    var number = locations[i][0].id;
    var marker_html = '<div id="' + number + '"><div class="rich-marker"><span class="number-id">' + number + '</span></div></div>';

    var marker = new RichMarker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      flat: true,
      anchor: RichMarkerPosition.MIDDLE,
      content: marker_html
    });
  }
  map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
  var minZoomLevel = 18;
  map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('zoom').innerHTML = map.getZoom();

    // Limit the zoom level
    if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);

    // for loop door locaties
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

      setMarkerSize(i);
    }
  });

  function setMarkerSize(i) {
    var infobox = locations[i][0].infobox;
    var id = locations[i][0].id;

    if (map.getZoom() === 18) {
      $('.rich-marker').css({
        'display': 'block',
        'width': '20px',
        'height': '20px'
      });
      /* $('.number-id').css({
        'display': 'block',
        'font-size': '12px'
      }); */

      if (id >= 100) {
        console.log(id);
        console.log($('[data-id="' + id + '"]'));

        $('#' + id).find('.number-id').css('font-size', '18px');
        $('#' + id).find('.number-id').css('color', 'red');
      }

      /* infobox.setOptions({
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-93, -22)
      }); */
    }

  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var locations = [
  [{
    id: 1,
    lat: 51.5239935252832,
    lng: 5.137663903579778,
    content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
  }],
  [{
    id: 2,
    lat: 51.523853342911906,
    lng: 5.1377765563584035,
    content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
  }],
  [{
    id: 3,
    lat: 51.5237298485607,
    lng: 5.137969675407476,
    content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
  }],
  [{
    id: 4,
    lat: 51.52355628836575,
    lng: 5.138066234932012,
    content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
  }],
  [{
    id: 5,
    lat: 51.52340275379578,
    lng: 5.138211074218816,
    content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
  }],
  [{
    id: 6,
    lat: 51.523199152806626,
    lng: 5.138382735595769,
    content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
  }],
  [{
    id: 7,
    lat: 51.5229955509073,
    lng: 5.138511481628484,
    content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
  }],
  [{
    id: 8,
    lat: 51.52280529912936,
    lng: 5.138543668136663,
    content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
  }],
  [{
    id: 9,
    lat: 51.523596340777075,
    lng: 5.138463201866216,
    content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
  }],
  [{
    id: 700,
    lat: 51.523372714362736,
    lng: 5.1386992362595265,
    content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'
  }],
  [{
    id: 101,
    lat: 51.52329594683302,
    lng: 5.138838711128301,
    content: 'Kids Jungalow Giraffe'
  }]
];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker/gh-pages/src/richmarker.js"></script>
<div id="zoom"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```